# HTML checkboxes array not sent in POST

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I'm using Laravel and AngularJS, I'm submitting a form that has some car information, and checkboxes to choose security features of a car, in the post request I can see all the parameters passed successfully but not the security array, I already put 'security' in the array of `$fillable` parameters.

```
class Car extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array('id', 'plate', 'details', 'security');
}
```

Here is the part of the form that has my checkboxes:

```
<div id="security" class="tab-pane fade">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                      <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="car.abs" name="security[abs]">
                        ABS
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                      <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="car.erd" name="security[erd]">
                        Electronic Brake Distribution (EBD)
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                      <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="car.break_assistant" name="security[break_assistant]">
                        Brake assistant
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

This is how I successfully submit the form and get all values passed but not `security`:

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: $.param($scope.car),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    }).then(function(response) {
        showSnackbar('Saved successfully');
    }, function(response) {
        showSnackbar('An error has occurred');
    });
```

What exactly I am doing wrong?

Comment: You'd need to demonstrate how you actually submit your data... but I have a feeling you need to define `security` as an array **within** your `$fillable` array.

Comment: I edited the question adding what you asked for. How do I add `security` as an array in `$fillable`?

Comment: I think I found the reason, I am missing the Angular tag `ng-model="car.security"` on my checkbox elements!

Comment: @Obsidian Age deserved that.

Comment: Yup, i noticed the Angular missing tags after he asked me to show the form submission way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I was missing the AngularJS tag `ng-model="car.security"` on my checkbox elements.